# ViewModels directory reference missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I dont know why the "ViewModels" folder reference is missed on my MVC5 login.cshtml file. Please checkout two screen shot to get clear idea about error.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: `WebApplication4.ViewModels` is, at best, a namespace, not a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your "ViewModels" folder please check "User.cs" and "UserLogin.cs" class. I think you didn't used its namespace correctly. That's why MVC may not recognising your "ViewModels" folder in reference. The test code bellow you can put on "User.cs" class. I think after you replace "User.cs" codes with mine your "ViewModels" folder should be listed.

User.cs code:

```
namespace WebApplication4.ViewModels
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this was the case. I was copying class codes from my another project. So the namespace was wrong. Thanks man. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
@using WebApplication4.ViewModels
```

if you wanna use namespace.

For model you have to pass Class not namespace.
For example

```
@model WebApplication4.ViewModels.UserLogin
```

for your UserLogin class. And please check if your class is in right namespace or paste code from UserLogin.cs